# Global locale for moment.js in a vuejs2 project

Tags: vuejs2, momentjs

At the moment in each component I set the locale in each created hook with:

```
...
created () {
  moment.locale('nl')
}
...
```

Is this possible to do at one spot that rules for all components?

I'm using the vue webpack template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use `Object.definePrototype`. Insert code below into your entry js file (`src/main.js` in webpack template).

```
import moment from 'moment';
// ...
moment.locale('nl');
Object.definePrototype(Vue.prototype, '$moment', { value: moment });
```

Then you will be able to use moment as `this.$moment()` in every component.
This solution is [introduced by Anthony Gore](https://medium.com/js-dojo/use-any-javascript-library-with-vue-js-3f7e2a4974a8) and I do think it meets your requirement here perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I this snipped above works but I created a plugin for it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10):

In VUE 2.5 can be done like this:

```
/* IN MAIN FILE */ 
import Moment from 'moment' 
Moment.locale(lang)
Vue.prototype.$moment = Moment
/* INSIDE A COMPONENT */
console.log(this.$moment().format("LL"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
created () {
  this.$root.$moment.locale("nl");
}
...
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** this code helps.

Comment: This will not work with the authors given conditions